# RavenDB BulkInsert returns "Bad request" when called from C#

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm working on a piece of C# code that moves records from one RavenDB database instance to another, modifying some values in the process. It works with simple IDocumentSession

```
sessionDestination.Store(timeout);
sessionDestination.SaveChanges();
```

but for the number of record I'm dealing with (over 15 thousand) inserting the records one by one is way too slow. I googled the recommended solution, which is to use BulkInsert. My code looks like this:

```
using (var bulkInsertDestination = storeDestination.BulkInsert())
{
   ...
   foreach (var timeout in timeouts)
   {
    ...
    bulkInsertDestination.Store(timeout);
```

I pretty much just retrieved a BulkInsertOperation, and swapped it with the IDocumentSession. (I used this example for reference https://gist.github.com/PureKrome/5522741)
But when I try to execute the bulkInsertDestination.Store(timeout); command, I get an exception - 400 bad request from the server:

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}
```

At first I thought maybe the RavenDB server is not set up to allow batch inserts. But when I import data from a dump file via the web interface, they are clearly being imported in batches of 512.

One thing I find fishy is that the command fails the first time I call it. The way I understand it is, the default batch size is 512, so when I call the Store() method, it should keep storing the records locally, and only send data to the DB server after it reaches 512. Yet it seems that the moment I put a record in it, it tries to send it to the database.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look at what is going on in Fiddler

Comment: I didn't feel like debugging the RavenDB API. Instead I used the session object, but only called SaveChanges after every nth record. It works just like buffering, it only took about 30 seconds to insert 15 000 records. Only problem is I get an exception if my session makes more than 30 insert calls. Some sort of limit in RavenDB. But I can fiddle with the batch size to avoid the problem, or recycle the session after 30 calls if that's not enough. What I'd like to know is, other than that, are there any practical drawbacks to this solution, anything that might cause it to fail?